# why did this transaction fail?

Tags: solidity, web3js, erc-20, ethereumjs

I have a smart contract on Ropsten that I'm testing: `0x813870feba76f27ec1AfcF79432e065A4839F7AB`

Transaction has failed(reverted).

What is the problem, because I don't see an error message

Transaction on Etherscan:
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x94f838aaa201af26818a339a8deb50e0a6e45678316a423ad0c238075d2470e1

Comment: looks like the function you call invokes 'transferFrom' on an ERC20 token.  Did you approve the transfer beforehand with another transaction?

Comment: no i havent, how would i do that?

Answer (score 1):

A @Chan-Ho says, there is a `transferFrom()` in the buy function, and you said you didn't `approve()` first, so that is the first problem.

This looks like the Token contract - AGI:

`erc20 = TOKEN(address(0x8eb24319393716668d768dcec29356ae9cffe285));`

You have to call the `approve()` function there to "authorize" the snet contract to pull some tokens from your account.

You'll see `buy` is going to pull `amount` (the first argument in your transaction, you set to 1). So snet needs an "allowance" of one or more. You sent that value by sending an `approve(args, ...)` to the token contract.

Have a look here for details: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20

The "spender" will be the snet contract where you sent the failed transaction. In summary, it's a two-step process.

Here's the code we're looking at. You're transaction set data there. https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x8eb24319393716668d768dcec29356ae9cffe285#code

Hope it helps.

Comment: ok i get that but where do i call teh approve function?
do i call it from the Ui, because i dont see teh approve function in my smart contract

Comment: There are lots of ways and we don't know if you used a UI, command line, MyEtherWallet, something else. I'll give you a tip if you give us a hint.

Comment: i used metamask

Comment: There must something else. From your comment on the other answer, I'm guessing you didn't use Remix to form the transaction for `buy`. In any case, MetaMask is fine for signing and your task is to send `approve(<snet_address", 1)` _TO_ the AGI contract. If should be _FROM_ the same account you plan to use to try `buy` again.

Comment: what are you saying dude?

Comment: In case it isn't clear, your sender/signer (from) will have to have at least 1 AGI so there are sufficient funds when you try to `buy()`. I can't send money it doesn't have.

Comment: I think you should edit your question to show the client-side steps you used to create the transaction that failed.

Comment: please havew a look here- tehy use the same contract with hex

Comment: whats your eth address i send you some agi and additionally you can also get them from ropsten.agi faucet

Comment: @yappytwan getting AGI from the Ropsten faucet won't help.  The AGI Ropsten contract is not the one listed as the token address in your cloned snet contract.  If you want your cloned contract to work, you need to use the tokens from your cloned token contract.

Comment: @yappytwan For instance, here's a Ropsten transaction with the real AGI contract: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x48a493e473bdb76fd88bdacf7ff9c7d6509403dd9835dfeb78cc0a0d965569d1 It sends my test account 10 AGI.  But it won't show up when I do `balanceOf` on *your* deployed token contract.  That's the one *your* snet contract thinks is the token contract.  Seems like the chief difficulty here is you don't understand what an ERC20 token is and you're trying to interact with a contract that manipulates ERC20 tokens...

Comment: just post a complete answer, that bullshit you post makes no sense dude- stop getting back and forth and answer my quesdtion, either post a guide or dont even respond

Comment: @RobHitchens-B9lab why you stop answering my question in the middle of it? What help is this if you quit talking in the middle of the conversation

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see @rob-hitchens-b9lab has answered the question beautifully while I was busy ;), so I'll give a short, cookbook answer of the steps

I don't know what you're using but most people are familiar with Remix,  so here are the steps in Remix:

1. In the "Solidity Compiler" tab, create and compile an `Erc20token.sol` file :

```
interface Erc20Token {
   function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
   function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
   function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
   function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
   function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
   function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}
```

2. In the "Deploy and Run Transactions" tab, use the token address `0x8eb24319393716668d768dcec29356ae9cffe285` from the snet contract (your contract), with the "At Address" option instead of "Deploy":

[image]

3. From the same tab, use the "approve" method of the contract.  I used `amount` equal to 1.  The approved address should be the snet contract, `0x813870feba76f27ec1AfcF79432e065A4839F7AB`.  ([Here's](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xd1556b0bad97c3ce6946bc4a673306fe5263c154d8e2a0d1a75436c91ea949a4) the approve transaction on Etherscan.)
4. Now go through similar steps as above to get your sns contract to appear in the "deployed contracts" section.  Use your snet contract's "buy" method, as you did before, making sure amount is at most the amount approved in step 3.

As you can see from Etherscan, I used some of my precious test Ether to do the steps above, so your contract will show a transaction from one of my dev accounts :) .

After doing all the above, I realized although I approved a token transfer, I don't actually have any of your tokens, so the final "buy" transaction would fail when trying to do the transfer.  I'm pretty confident it would work otherwise though.

Comment: makes absolutley no sense to do it like that

Comment: It does, actually.

Comment: i dont like to do it that way, nobody is doing it that complicated, i appreciate your help but its not a help cause its a weird way of doing it

Comment: and none of your transactions went through, so what good is this doing?

Comment: The approve transaction went through.  If you have tokens in your account and you do this approve transaction as I did, then the transaction you've been trying should work.  But why not try to get the approve transaction working and then try your original transaction?  `transferFrom` will not work on an ERC20 token without `approve` first.  So you have to do the `approve` transaction to progress in what you're attempting anyway.  And yes, ERC20 is clunky / complicated.  Plenty of good Medium articles if the original EIP Rob linked you to is not to your taste.

Comment: Simple way to settle this is, you can send my test address some of your tokens.  Then my claim is my "buy" should work after that.

Comment: ok lets try that- post your eth address i send you some ropsten agi

Comment: As I hopefully clarified in my remarks to the *other* answer (Rob's), you need to send *your* token to my address, not the real AGI Ropsten token, since that's not the one you're using.  In other words,use the contract at `0x8eB24319393716668D768dCEC29356ae9CfFe285` to send to my address `0x592314749dc09d9e4a152d8ac804fc66134941cf`.

Comment: i dont get it, i followed above steps and i was able to do everything but i still cant transfer any token nor can i buy anything

Comment: can you not just write me an idiot prove tutorial, i pay you for it dont worry

Comment: I don't see any further transactions after my approve transaction on your token contract:  https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x8eb24319393716668d768dcec29356ae9cffe285

Comment: i understand i eed to first approve teh tranasction from the agi contract and than i can use the amount i wsa asking for approval to interact with the contract

Comment: and why do i need a new contract- the contract already has the same functions why do i need to create a new contract called erc20token.sol- this approve is already included in my code

Comment: contract TOKEN {
   function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
   function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
   function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
   function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
   function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
   function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}
this is already in my contract- why create a new 1??

Comment: i deployed the erc20token.sol at address from agi- ropsten, than i approved tranascation over 1 agi to snet contract address - which worked but when i actually try to buy token - i get in meatamsk an error (ALERT: Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code.)

Comment: i cant send you any token- it doesnt work because my testnet agi dont show up- i tried through the contract and i tried it now manually insufficient balance tahtswhy i get an error, but if you look at my ropsten address- i have some. 
now another thing i just realized is that my SNET balance shows up- well token was added but balance is 0

Comment: oki finally got it to work, thanks for your patience guys

Comment: @yappytwan glad things came together for you!

Comment: no, its not workiing

Comment: @RobHitchens-B9lab its not working,i tried all different options and i cant buy anything. And why do i need a erc20token.sol? i have the same function already inside my code?

Comment: You don't need to have a separate file if you don't wish.  It all depends on how you setup your IDE/dev environment.  The point is you have to interact with the token at an address.  Use the address of the token contract you wish to have tokens of.  This must be the address used in your snet contract as the token address.

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh Please post a turorial on how to do this, this things dont work whats posted up there

Comment: please jsut post a tutorial. a step by step guide. i tried every thing- what should i do withthe contract after deploying it on at address? i goes through with the approve function but after that nothing works. And i need no extr file. i just want to use this thing at 1 file.

Comment: just please post a simple tutorial using my, code. i need no other extra erc20token file and none of that. just make a simple stupid step by step guide on how to do this:

Comment: it seems like what you really need help on is just being able to interact with a deployed contract, particularly an ERC20 token.  Here's a good intro to Remix:  https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/19/testing-and-deploying-smart-contracts-with-remix/ . Here's another intro to ERC20 by the same authors: https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/01/30/writing-an-erc20-token-contract/

Comment: if you just want to use one file, e.g. the snet contract code from Etherscan, you can just compile it in Remix, and use a dropdown menu in the "deploy and run" tab to select "TOKEN" to use with "Address At" button.

Comment: please just post a tutorial

Comment: what contract do i need to compile the TOKEN contract right? and than what? Just post a turial with images or something, cause everythign you guys have posted i tried but nothing works

Comment: Now go through similar steps as above to get your sns contract to appear in the "deployed contracts" section. Use your snet contract's "buy" method, as you did before, making sure amount is at most the amount approved in step 3. -- what do i eed to do? If i use at address than snet is contract owner and if i "deploy" it at my address this thing doesnt work

Comment: @RobHitchens-B9lab How do i mae my contract appear there? do i eed to redploy the whole contract again or do I need to deploy it under at address and yes which address? Be more specific in your answer, its not a help otherwise

Comment: @RobHitchens-B9lab I was only able to get it to approve after that nothing works. Please post a whole guide on how to do this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103314/discussion-between-yappy-twan-and-chan-ho-suh).

Comment: why is it so difficult to post an answer to this?

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh He was finally able to send u token from with hin the contract using teh transfer function, however i still cant use the buy fuction